# Storing asp:repeater iteration properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, iteration

I found myself having to modify a legacy project with a list of products being listed in a .ascx file using an asp:repeater control, and I have to add a Google Tag Manager script (GTM from now) every time the name of the product (an HTML anchor) is clicked.

My approach has been trying to store all properties of the products in javascript variables inside the  tag and calling them in the anchor onclick event, like this:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="RpProductos" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div id="ListadoProductos">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <script>
                var ruta = '<%# HtmlRutaPagina(Eval("IdProducto"),(string) Eval("Titulo")) %>';

                var producto = {
                    "name": "<%# Eval("Titulo")%>",
                    "id": "<%# Eval("IdProducto")%>",
                    "price": "<%#Eval("Precio")%>",
                    "brand": "<%# Eval("Autor")%>",
                    "category": "<%# HtmlTipoProducto((int)Eval("IdTipoProducto")) %>",
                    "variant": "",
                    "list": "Search Results",
                    "position": contadorProductos
                };

                window[<%# Eval("IdProducto")%>] = producto;
                impresionesGTM.push(window[<%# Eval("IdProducto")%>]);
                function clickProducto(ruta,producto) {
                    scriptGTMClick(ruta, producto);
                    window.location = ruta;
                }
            </script>

            <div class="ImgProducto">
                <a onclick="clickProducto(ruta, producto);" title='<%# Eval("titulo")%>'>
                    <img src='<%# HtmlRutaImg((int)Eval("idproducto")) %>' alt='<%# Eval("Titulo")%>' title='<%# Eval("Titulo")%>' width="80" /></a>
            </div>
            <h2><a href='<%# HtmlRutaPagina((int)Eval("idproducto"),(string) Eval("titulo")) %>' title='<%# Eval("titulo")%>'><%# Eval("titulo")%></a></h2>
            <div class="CajaLisCabecera">
                <p class="col25">Tipo: <span class="strong"><%# HtmlTipoProducto((int)Eval("idtipoproducto")) %></span></p>
                <p class="col75">Subcategor&iacute;a: <span class="strong"><%# HtmlTipoSubCategoria((int) Eval("idsubcategoria")) %> </span></p>
                <p>Autor: <span class="strong"><%# Eval("Autor") %></span></p>
                <div><%#Eval("DESCRIPCIONBREVE") %></div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

But no matter how many ways I try (even inserting the full product object inside de "onclick" attribute, it always gives me the error "**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.**"

I've been struggling with this for several hours and though that probably some smart guys here may know the answer... any ideas about how could I deal with this?
I have thought on storing all needed variables inside  tags, but it's not very clean.

As a last note, I'd prefer a solution that does not involve removing the asp:repeater or modifying a lot of server code, because I'll have to repeat the process and can last very long even with out it...

Comment: I tested your snippet. It works as it should. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I just tried to run it in a clean project and it's true that setting the DataSource as a new List works smoothly. My code is running inside a DotNetNuke module, I don't know if it may be related to the problem... Anyway you made me look it from another perspective, thanks!